# Is there a network description language and a tool to render it visual?

Tags: networking

I really don't like to draw network diagrams manually.

Aren't there tools which could let me describe the network in a structured textual format and get a nice picture rendered?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, there is [GraphViz](http://www.graphviz.org/) which renders from the [dot language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOT_%28graph_description_language%29). (N.B. The 'Graph' bit referrs to graphs in the sense of connected nodes and edges, not bar graphs and line graphs).

It renders basic pictures by default, but is very configurable - see the gallery, or Google Image search for examples - but not *easily* configurable beyond coloured lines, dotted lines and shapes. You can get "tidy" pictures with a bit of effort. "Nice" is more debatable.

Sadly, it is the product of decades of time, academia and open source; and by that I mean very effective, feature filled and capable, but also ugly, opinionated, and gratingly temperamental.

I used to know of a website which would render GraphViz diagrams as you type them, but I haven't been able to find it recently. Anyone know it?

There is also a connection from the dot language into Visio, here: http://www.calvert.ch/graphvizio/ ( and http://graphvizio.sourceforge.net/ ). I have not used this.

Comment: A nice answer. Thank you. Though too low-level. I was thinking about something specifically meant for network diagramming. E.g. I describe every host (PC/router/server/printer/etc), every interface of theirs, every switch, every physical connection (including the media used), geography (which node is in which room/floor/building) as a separate record to get a reasonable looking  printable graphical network documentation rendered.